# In PostgreSQL, how to move data already stored on SSD to HDD?

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

I'm storing time-series data of some products to my DB server.

- Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
- PostgreSQL 15.x
- SSD: 5TB with RAID 5 (OS and Postgres installed)
- HDD: 6TB with RAID 5 (my target of data migration)

As data comes in, it is stored in the SSD.
At this time, the amount of data that comes in is quite large and becomes quite burdensome to keep as time passes, or as there are more products.
Due to the nature of time-series data, old data(more than a month old by my standards) become less valuable and less sought after over time.

[image: Here is what it looks like]

So I want to transfer old data to HDD as it is.

As I caputured, the actual time-series data is stored in `sqlt_data_1_2023_XX` table, and as you can see, the table is automatically created as the month changes.

Here's what I want or wonder:
Can the table where the data is stored be moved from one disk to another while keeping the logical structure intact?
The reason why we want the logical structure(schema, as I caputred) to be the same is that even if the location where the data is stored changes, the 3rd-party application(web monitoring) must refer to the time series data.

Please comment if my explanation is ambiguous or if you need additional information for a solution.
Thank you in advance.

Since I am a beginner in PostgreSQL, I saw keywords such as 'table partitioning' and 'tablespace' when I searched in advance.
But before I study and understand this term, I want to make sure my requirements are implementable first.

Comment: What I understand is that you want to do is basically migrate your databases/tables from one disk to another. What you can do is Make a Backup and then copy to Restore it on target disk. If you are MS-DOS (Cmd.exe) and both disks are communicable, then you can use `robocopy` command to copy all the files from `<your_postgres_folder_path>` to the destination disk `<path>`. You can also consider using `replication` of your DB tables.

Comment: @Raky: Please remove this comment, it's a recipe for disaster.

Comment: @Raky I have read your comment, unfortunately, however, your advice does not seem to applicable to the situation of the problem at hand. At the very beginnig of the question, I mentioned the OS, Ubuntu Linux, of the server I use.
But anayway thank you for paying attention to my question and writing comments.

Comment: I know, that's Why I deleted my Answer. Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a use case for tablespaces. Create a tablespace on the spinning disk:

```
CREATE TABLESPACE slow LOCATION '/mountpoint/of/hdd/somedir'
   (seq_page_cost = 5.0, random_page_cost = 10.0);
```

The parameters indicate that that disk is much slower. `/mountpoint/of/hdd/somedir` must be an existing directory that belongs to the PostgreSQL operating system user.

Whenever one partition/table gets too old, move it to the slow tablespace:

```
ALTER TABLE some_table SET TABLESPACE slow;
```

The only restriction is that the table is not accessible while it is being moved. If that is a problem for you, you could choose an alternative course:

- make sure that your application does not write to the table in question
- create a copy of the table on the slow tablespace
- drop the original table and rename the new one to the old name

Comment: Dear Laurenz Albe, Can you please elaborate your response. I am not in tune... Maybe my understanding of the question and response are different.

Comment: I didn't ask for tutorials. But thanks for responding, though harsh. Keeping in view my misunderstanding of the question and lack of info on tablespace, I have deleted my response. I have learnt a new thing anyways... And will be exploring to use it in my projects. Thanks

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe : Thank you for answering my question. `The only restriction is that the table is not accessible while it is being moved.` This part was the most helpful to me and would save my meaningless time. As a web developer, I was most curious about whether I could use SQL queries to read data that was moved to HDD the same way as data still stored on SSD using JDBC Connection in the 3rd-party web application even after moving physical storage locations using tablespace.

Comment: after moving is done all should be fine. while it's being moved it will be unaccessible.